# Reassign/Reset all auto increment values in a table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, reset

I have a table with an auto increment column `uid`. Over the time, the table has filled and some entries were deleted. I want to reassign all auto increment values of my table and I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718674). But I want to know, if there is a more proper way to do this and if not, does this method keep the sorting of the rows?

Comment: What made you conclude that the idea presented in the linked post are not efficient? and yes, it will keep the sorting order. Just try it and see yourself.

Comment: I thought, that deleting the column and adding a new column is just a workaround for this problem. And thank you :)